# Windows Workflow 4.5 and external rules

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, c#-5.0

So with .NET 4.5, a workflow is comprised of activities.  Ive done some simple examples with WF 4.5 and hosted it in a WCF service etc.  Great, but I now am looking at building a simple rules type processing service and want to keep the rules stored seperately so that someone other than myself can edit them.

This naturally lead me down the road of researching rules engine.  I came across examples that referenced the 3.5 WF way of doing things.
One of the examples I was looking through was this
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd349785.aspx

Then I browsed the MS Workflow migration documents, especially the one concerning rules. Im still confused.

So in general, my question is - How can I use and edit rules kept externally to a workflow assembly, but use .NET 4.5 and not have to use any legacy components?

**[update]**
Anyone finding this thread and facing the same WF3 -vs- WF4 dilema regarding the evaluation and use of "rules" will find the following helpful.  Its a way of doing rules the WF4 way. 
http://www.nilzorblog.com/2011/11/using-wf4-as-rule-engine.html

Comment: You have to code it.  3.5 rules aren't compatible (in a plugin way, not like in a code-it-in-yourself way) with 4.5

Comment: Im not sure what you mean.  I managed to find a post mentioning the similar situation im in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11771332/how-to-create-a-rules-file-in-workflow-foundation-4-5-vs2012   However, that post doesnt cover how to handle editing the rules.

Comment: You can use the rules framework in any type of .net application.  That includes workflows.  However, WF4 knows nothing of the rules framework, and does not use it.  Therefore, if you want to use rules, then you must code for it.